# How to round, format, and conditionally trim zeros from floats?

Tags: php, floating-point, conditional-statements, number-formatting, decimal-point

I have written a custom function which must call `number_format()` to round my input number (float) to predetermined number of decimal places (the number of decimal places should cap at 5) and make modifications to the decimal character and the thousands delimiter.

After the number is rounded and formatted, I also wish to conditionally trim some of the trailing zeros from the decimal value.

Specifically, if the input value is to be rounded to 0, 1, or 2 decimal places, then no zero trimming is necessary.  However, if the rounding is to 3 or more places, then trailing zeros can be removed until only two decimal places remain.

Here is a matrix of test cases and my desired output:

```
                |      D    E    C    I    M    A    L      P    L    A    C    E    S   
     INPUT      |   0   |    1    |     2    |     3     |     4      |      5      |       6
----------------+-------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+------------
1.01            |     1 |     1,0 |     1,01 |     1,01  |     1,01   |     1,01    |     1,01
----------------+-------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+------------
1.044           |     1 |     1,0 |     1,04 |     1,044 |     1,044  |     1,044   |     1,044
----------------+-------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+------------
0.240000        |     0 |     0,2 |     0,24 |     0,24  |     0,24   |     0,24    |     0,24
----------------+-------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+------------
0.200           |     0 |     0,2 |     0,20 |     0,20  |     0,20   |     0,20    |     0,20
----------------+-------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+------------
0.24540         |     0 |     0,2 |     0,25 |     0,245 |     0,2454 |     0,2454  |     0,2454
----------------+-------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+------------
0.24546         |     0 |     0,2 |     0,25 |     0,245 |     0,2455 |     0,24546 |     0,24546
----------------+-------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+------------
6500.00         | 6 500 | 6 500,0 | 6 500,00 | 6 500,00  | 6 500,00   | 6 500,00    | 6 500,00
----------------+-------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+------------
3760.54         | 3 761 | 3 760,5 | 3 760,54 | 3 760,54  | 3 760,54   | 3 760,54    | 3 760,54
----------------+-------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+------------
3760.000000000  | 3 760 | 3 760,0 | 3 760,00 | 3 760,00  | 3 760,00   | 3 760,00    | 3 760,00
----------------+-------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+------------
0.04000         |     0 |     0,0 |     0,04 |     0,04  |     0,04   |     0,04    |     0,04
----------------+-------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+------------
1.000000        |     1 |     1,0 |     1,00 |     1,00  |     1,00   |     1,00    |     1,00
----------------+-------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+------------
1.000005        |     1 |     1,0 |     1,00 |     1,00  |     1,00   |     1,00001 |     1,00001
```

This is my current code:

```
function format($number, $decimal=0, $thousands=' ')
{
    $number = number_format($number, $decimal, '.', '');

    $whole    = floor($number);
    $fraction = $number - $whole;

    if(!(int)$fraction && $decimal > 2) {
        $decimal = 2;
    }

    if (false !== strpos($number, '.')) {
        $number = rtrim(rtrim($number, '0'), '.');
    }

    $number = number_format($number, $decimal, '.', $thousands);

    return $number;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have rewritten my solution and confirmed it to be as accurate as your posted solution with the sample strings provided.

If my solution fails in your project, please provide new sample data that will expose the issue.

Rules, as I understand them:

1. `number_format()` MUST be the first manipulation on `$number` so that rounding is performed and output accuracy is maintained.
2. You have a hard-coded upper limit on decimal length which is `5`.
3. When the passed `$decimals` parameter is greater than `2`, it is acceptable for the trailing zeros to be removed until there are only two digits remaining.

Note, because the output from `number_format()` will be a string that cannot be processed as a number AND because the trimming process requires several steps to assess and execute, I'll employ a single regex pattern to reduce code bloat.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/iLB63))

```
function format($number, $decimals = 2, $dec_point = ',', $thousands_sep = ' ') {
    $number = number_format($number, min(5, $decimals), $dec_point, $thousands_sep);  // round to decimal max
    return preg_replace("~".preg_quote($dec_point, '~')."\d{".min(2, $decimals)."}[^0]*\K0+$~", '', $number);  // trim zeros (if any, beyond minimum allowance) from right side of decimal character
}
```

Of course, you can pull out the `min()` and `preg_quote()` calls if you wish to declare single-use variables; or alternatively, if you like freakishly long one-liners:

```
function format($number, $decimals = 2, $dec_point = ',', $thousands_sep = ' ') {
    return preg_replace("~".preg_quote($dec_point, '~')."\d{".min(2, $decimals)."}[^0]*\K0+$~", '', number_format($number, min(5, $decimals), $dec_point, $thousands_sep));
}
```

Pattern Breakdown:

```
"                       #double-quote-wrap the expression to allow variables to be parsed
~                       #pattern delimiter
".preg_quote($dec_point, '~')."  #match the (escaped when necessary) value of `$dec_point`match the value declared as $dec_point
\d{".min(2, $decimals)."}        #match any two digits (if $decimals<2 then use $decimals else use 2 as "quantifier)
[^0]*                   #match zero or more non-zero characters (could have also used [1-9])
\K                      #restart the fullstring match (release/forget all previously matched characters
0+                      #match one or more occurrences of the character: 0
$                       #match the end of the string
~                       #pattern delimiter
"                       #close double-quoted expression
```

As per the desired effect, this pattern will only *remove* trailing zeros where appropriate/applicable.  It will not *add* zeros to the right side of the string.

Comment: Thanks your answer. Your code is every keep two decimals. So, I have to keep two decimals if decimal values is largest then two. And I need to round the numbers if no decimals.
https://3v4l.org/vLks1

Comment: @Dersy I've adjusted my answer to work just like your answer's function.

Comment: Yes, it was a complete overwrite. @Lawrence  Hopefully the OP will see that this level of clarity is important for future questions.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve your desired results while controlling the number of digits with a decimals parameter.

[`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) pads a number to the number of decimals that are asked. Since we need a maximal number of possible digits, `0` being trimmed all the time, it's not optimal to use that.

I have a preference for strings when it comes to working with floats, and the probability is good that they will appear as so from a database, so we design accordingly.

```
// note: I assume PHP >= 7.1

echo format('3760.541234', 2);
// "3 760,54"

function format(string $number, int $decimal = 0): string
{
    if (strpos($number, '.') === false) {
        return makeNumber($number);
    }

    [$whole, $fraction] = explode('.', $number);

    return makeNumber($whole) . ($fraction > 0 ? (',' . makeDecimals($fraction, $decimal)) : '');
}

function makeDecimals(string $decimals, int $limit): string
{
    if (\strlen($decimals) === 0) {
        throw new \LogicException('we are formatting an empty string');
    }
    return substr(rtrim($decimals, '0'), 0, $limit);
}

function makeNumber(string $number): string
{
    return ltrim(strrev(chunk_split(strrev($number), 3, ' ')), ' ');
}
```

---

If you are interested, here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Zvax/1a35a8b5ed2a02dc2610f73aad249611) of the file I used to create this, along with a phpunit test class. You can add your own tests to make sure all the cases you want work (that also requires to use phpunit, but that is a whole other topic).

Comment: https://3v4l.org/aH89V
 Your method doesn't `round()` like `number_format()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php#67173 and @Lawrence please undelete your answer.

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes, it does not. Why?

Comment: It seems like a necessary feature with the OP's question -- where a max-decimal value is a function argument.  If the number has more (retained) decimal values than the max decimal allows, your method will truncate instead of round.

Comment: It is not clear from OP's question, no, that it is a requirement. I'll gladly make changes if they explicitely say that.

Comment: Fair enough.  I think this question probably shouldn't have been answered until the question was clarified ... by the OP

Comment: Why so? Everything from the question is clear. This is not a blatant missing piece of information.

Comment: after the OP posted a solution, I was able to reverse engineer a clear question. You will be able to adjust your answer with certainty (if you care to).

Comment: wow, great work :) can't really rework it now, and I feel your answer covers it up already, but I'll try to get to it later. thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Today morning I solved it.

```
    function format($number, $decimals=2, $dec_point = ',', $thousands_sep = ' ') {

    $decimals = (int)$decimals;

    if($decimals > 5) {
      $decimals = 5; //Maximum decimals limit..
    }

    $number = number_format((float)$number, $decimals, $dec_point, $thousands_sep);

    if(strpos($number, $dec_point) === false) {
       return $number; //No decimal values..
    }

    $splArr = explode($dec_point, $number);
    $split = array_reverse(str_split($splArr[1]));

    foreach($split as $cleanNum)
    {
      if($decimals > 2 && $cleanNum === '0') { //Keep minimum two decimals.
        $number = substr($number, 0, -1);
        $decimals--;
       } else {
         break; //Found a non zero number.
       }
    }

    return rtrim($number,$dec_point);
}

$test = [
    '1.01',
    '1.044',
    '0.240000',
    '0.200',
    '0.24540',
    '0.24546',
    '6500.00',
    '3760.54',
    '3760.000000000',
    '0.04000',
    '1.000000'
];

foreach ($test as $number) {
    echo format($number, 6).PHP_EOL;
}
```

Result is:

```
1,01 
1,044 
0,24 
0,20 
0,2454 
0,24546 
6 500,00 
3 760,54 
3 760,00 
0,04 
1,00
```

Thank you so much, everyone.